# The response XML is getting with some space after running collection runner in Postman

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, api-testing, data-driven, postman

I'm using collection for the XML service in Postman, After the execution, I got the results successfully but when am seeing the test results the response body is coming with some extra space for each parameter and value

Ex:
[image]

Please let me know the solution for this